# CSVを読み込む際、半角スペースがnullに変換されてしまう

Tags: c#

CSVファイルをSQLServerに取り込もうとしています。

データベース内のカラムが「char(2)not null」で定義しているカラムにデータを挿入する際、CSV上では半角スペース2文字のカラムがnullと判定されてしまい、以下のメッセージがスローされてしまいます。

```
Column 'ColumnNameX' で DBNull.Value を使用できません。
```

CSVファイルの中では (こんな感じで `"  "` ) ダブルクォーテーションで囲い、明示的に空白であることを示したつもりなのですが、空白を空白として処理するのには何かオプションの指定があるのでしょうか？

```
public static void DoConnect()
{
    //接続文字列の構成
    string connectionString = @"Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)}; DBQ=.\";
    string dbStr = @"Persist Security Info = False; database = MYDB; server = localserver; UID = sa; PWD = xxxxxx;";

    using (OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            //データベース接続のOpen
            conn.Open();

            //CSVを読む
            OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME.csv", conn);
            OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            //データ型をキチンとするならSchemaを使う事！
            //DataTable t = reader.GetSchemaTable();

            //入れ込む先のDBへ接続
            using (SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection(dbStr))
            {
                //接続
                scon.Open();
                SqlTransaction trn = scon.BeginTransaction();   //トランザクション開始
                try
                {
                    SqlBulkCopy copy = new SqlBulkCopy(scon, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls, trn);  //コピーするときにトランザクションを結びつける
                    copy.DestinationTableName = "TABLE_NAME";
                    //そのままダイレクトに入れ込むべし
                    copy.WriteToServer(reader);     //★★★★　半角スペースがnullになってしまう

                    trn.Commit();                                   //コミット                        
                }catch(SqlException ex)
                {
                    trn.Rollback();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    trn.Rollback();
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn != null)
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**追記:**

最初の質問に以下のようなコードを追加して取得してきたデータの中身を確認したところ、半角スペースのところがnullで読み込まれていました。

半角スペースをNULLではなく、半角スペースのまま読み込むことは出来ないでしょうか。

```
DataTable t = new DataTable();
t.Load(reader);

//結果表示
foreach (DataRow row in t.Rows)
{
    foreach (object item in row.ItemArray)
    {
        Console.Write(item.ToString() + ",");
    }
    Console.WriteLine(" ");
}
```

Comment: `OdbcDataReader`が読み込んだ時点で`null`になっているのであれば`SqlBulkCopy`およびSQL Serverは無関係になるはずです。逆に正しく`"  "`が読み込めているのであればCSVは無関係です。原因を切り分けた上で質問を見直してください。

Comment: 版数・関連性・適切か等の諸々が不明ですが、この辺の記事が類似現象のように見えます。[BULK INSERTについて](https://okwave.jp/qa/q7044390.html), [一括インポート中の NULL または既定値の保持 (SQL Server)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/relational-databases/import-export/keep-nulls-or-use-default-values-during-bulk-import-sql-server?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15), [SQL ServerにCSVファイル or Excelファイルからデータをインポートする際に注意（NOT NULLと改行）すること。](https://final.hateblo.jp/entry/2017/02/19/210531)

Comment: OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderでの読み込みで細かい指定が出来ないようなら、`CsvHelper`を応用する [CsvDataReader](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/csvdatareader/) あるいは逆の話題かもしれないこちら [NullValues Option Not Working When Loading to DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54545023/9014308) とか自作の読み取り処理を`IDataReader`として作成して [IEnumerable から IDataReader へ変換](https://qiita.com/st450/items/831d90990658e023a679) 試してみてはどうでしょう？ 他にこんなのとか。[基本　CSVファイルをDataTableに読み込んで表示する](https://www.oborodukiyo.info/Forms/VS2008/F-ReadCSVToDataTable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

あまり詳しくないのですが、SQLにおいて末尾の空白の扱いは割と曖昧です。例えばSQL Serverにおいても[`SET ANSI_PADDING`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-padding-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)という設定が用意されており、`OFF`にすると末尾の空白を削ります。

[Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/microsoft-odbc-desktop-database-drivers?view=sql-server-ver15)についてドキュメントを確認しましたが、この辺りを制御するオプションは用意されていませんでした。例えば[Schema.ini](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/schema-ini-file-text-file-driver?view=sql-server-ver15)を用意して、`char(2)`等と明示しても末尾の空白は削られることを確認しました。

結局、

- 読み込んだ後で`char(2) not null`を満たすようにC#側で編集する
- CsvHelperなど他のライブラリを使用する

しかなさそうです。

Comment: Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)は諦めてC#でCSVを読み込むときにNULLだったら片っ端からスペース1個に変換するということで無理やり解決しました